# Cosigner bought a new car

Tags: united-states, auto-loan, co-sign

I bought a car last year but I needed a cosigner.

This past month the cosigner also bought a car.

If the cosigner doesn't make payments on time on their car payment, will it impact my credit since they are a cosigner on my loan?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "getting a car out".

Comment: Are you a cosigner on their loan for their car?  Or are they just a cosigner on your car's loan?  I'm assuming that "got a car out" means that you purchased the car.  And that you each borrowed money to purchase the car.  Also, what country is this?

Comment: I am the primary on my car loan. On the cosigner's loan I'm not. And I'm in the USA

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer. Let us know if the edits are incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing that ties you together is the car loan he consigned. Someone must make that payment or both your scores will suffer.

If he defaults on other debts, your score isn't impacted, as you didn't sign for those debts, only yours. The only thing that comes to mind is if he files for bankruptcy, and has all debts discharged. In that case you may lose him as a guarantor on your loan.

Comment: Losing him as guarantor, would that be a problem for the poster? I can see that the bank would be unhappy.